# Identity Server DefaultViewService JSON issue

Tags: json, identityserver3

I am trying to replace login page with custom login page using below link

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/DefaultViewService.html

Note - I am not facing this issue when i use partial view.

But my model Json is kind of wired, I am unable to get property value using {{model.logoutUrl}}

[image: Image showing model.logout url As is]

Strange but model is present but i am not able to get that value because it seems it has 2 curly braces and invalid JSON. [![Image showing model JSON][2]][2]

Any help will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: If you're not using a partial view - what exactly are you doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're making use of full views (like `login.html` as opposed to the partial `_login.html` which makes use of the `layout.html`), make sure to include the full model, and the identityserver js scripts that picks up the model and uses the templating of Angular to render the views yourself in each view.

```
<script id='modelJson' type='application/json'>{model}</script>
<script src="{applicationPath}/assets/scripts.2.5.0.js"></script> (or whatever version you're on)
{scripts}
```

Or in other words: when you're not using the partials, you will need to do whatever is normally in the layout file in each view.

[source](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/DefaultViewService/PageAssets/layout.html#L32)

Comment: Thanks John.. It was my bad.. i realized it later/

Comment: No problem! Feel free to mark it as answered if this closed your issue, @prvnsaini